# Force nested div to show on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some code similar to the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="darkOverlay"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="whiteText">I need to be clear bright white!</div>
</div>
```

When I click a button, I give the divs the following properties:

```
$('#darkOverlay').css('background-color','rgba(50,50,50,0.5)');
$('#darkOverlay').css('z-index','100');
$('#whiteText').css('display','block');
$('#whiteText').css('z-index','500');
```

So essentially I make darkOverlay dark-translucent and bring it to the front. And then I also show the white text and bring it to the (even more) front.

However, it seems that the darkOverlay still casts its translucency on top of my white text. This causes the white text not to appear as white as I need it to be. What should I do to make sure my white text stands out?

**CSS [on page load]**

```
#darkOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-100;
}

#whiteText {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the actual CSS definitions of all of these three divs? Are there any?

Comment: @Tomalla, I've added it above. There's really not much though.

Comment: seems to be working, you may have other css causing the problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kLzdh

Comment: Same here, the text is not covered by anything. But at the same time it's also not white. Or at least the definitions don't imply it; maybe it's inherited. Nevertheless, code's good.

Comment: I can't make it fail. Do you have an online example?

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess now I know something else is causing me this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the white text that's at issue, it's because nothing ever sets the color to white.

```
 $('#whiteText').css('color','white');
```

Or complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
<style>
#darkOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-100;
}

#whiteText {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="darkOverlay"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="whiteText">I need to be clear bright white!</div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative">
   <button id="clickme">clickme</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$("#clickme").click(function(e) {
$('#darkOverlay').css('background-color','rgba(50,50,50,0.5)');
$('#darkOverlay').css('z-index','100');
$('#whiteText').css('color','white');
$('#whiteText').css('display','block');
$('#whiteText').css('z-index','500');
});
</script>
</html>
```